# How to get the part number of any ssd using linux command?

Tags: linux

How to get the part number of any ssd using linux command ?

Comment: which one is the part number?

Comment: what is a part number?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you mean this, but using the standard tools in Debian GNU/Linux without installing anything additional, you can display information using the following commands:

`sudo /sbin/dmidecode`

`lsusb`

Display information about all block devices, including SSDs.

The output will include columns for NAME, MODEL, SERIAL, SIZE, and TYPE.

`lsblk -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,TYPE`

or

`lsblk -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,TYPE | grep "sd*"`

or

Here is another approach from **@cas** for `lsblk` with the `-d` option, outputting as `JSON` and for `NVMe` drives.

- Exclude partition details from lsblk's output with the -d (--nodeps) option

`lsblk -d -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,TYPE /dev/sd?`

- Output in json format

`lsblk -d -J -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,TYPE /dev/sd?`

- With a pair of nvme drives

`lsblk -d -J -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,TYPE /dev/nvme[01]n1`

If you know your device with `lsblk`(**sda,sdb,sdX,etc..**) you can use this(change **[sda]** with your device):

`udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda`

`udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep -E "ID_SERIAL|ID_SCSI_SERIAL"`

or

`sudo /sbin/smartctl -i /dev/sda`

`sudo /sbin/smartctl -i /dev/sda | grep "Serial Number"`

If you install further programs, you can display the following:

*Display info about all hardware*

```
inxi -Fxz

hwinfo --short

lshw  -short
```

*Show detailed information about a specific disk drive:*

```
hdparm -i /dev/sda
```

**The exact output format might vary depending on the Linux distribution and version, but the information you need should be present in the output.**

Comment: +1.   BTW, you can exclude partition details from `lsblk`'s output with the `-d` (`--nodeps`) option.  And you can get json output with lsblk's `-J` option.  e.g. `lsblk -d -J -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,TYPE /dev/sd?` (or, on my system with a pair of nvme drives: `lsblk -d -J -o NAME,MODEL,SERIAL,SIZE,TYPE /dev/nvme[01]n1`)